# Python 2.7: Detect DELETE key pressed on raw_input

Tags: python, input, console-application, special-characters

I am preparing a very simple script and I need the user to input certain values. At a certain point, I want to offer the chance to reuse an existing value or delete it if the user input is the DELETE key (the user presses DELETE and then Enter) but I don't seem to be able to find a satisfactory answer (which I find rather surprising...) It's just a helper script, so I was trying to avoid more advanced stuff such as [PyHook](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/) and things like that.

This is the chunk I'm interested in:

```
if reusable_params:
    for key in list(k for k in config_dict.keys() if k not in ["mac", "base_url", "command_name"]):
        msg = "Enter new value for parameter {0}. Press ENTER to reuse the previous {1}. Press DELETE+ENTER to remove this key.".format(key, config_dict[key])
        input = unicode(raw_input(msg).strip().decode(sys.stdin.encoding))
        logging.debug("input: %s, len(input) %s" % (input, len(input))
```

Pressing DELETE+Enter returns a unicode looking 4 characters string:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `raw_input` isn't capable of capturing single keystrokes (besides obviously the Enter key). If you are truly trying to keep your script simple, your best bet is to abandon this feature in favor of a slightly more tractable one (i.e. press Enter without entering any input to bring up a list of previously entered commands, press Enter again to execute the last command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [`pykeylogger`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page), allows you to capture the keyboard events, another options is to use `pygame`, which has great key-event support.

For **`pygame`**:

Specifically, you might want to take a look at this [page](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) (`pygame.keys`),

```
K_DELETE              delete #thanks to @7stud
```

So you can probably do something like this,

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_DELETE]:
           #your code here...
```

For **`pykeylogger`**, from [here](https://github.com/amoffat/pykeylogger/):

```
import keylogger
import time

now = time.time()
done = lambda: time.time() > now + 60
def print_keys(t, modifiers, keys): print "%.2f   %r   %r" % (t, keys, modifiers)

keylogger.log(done, print_keys)
```

Comment: A backspace(ascii code 8) is not equivalent to delete(ascii code 127).  If you look farther down the list it shows: `K_DELETE`

Answer (score 1):

Your cmd window is a piece of software, i.e. a computer program.  When you hit the delete key in a cmd window, the cmd window is programmed so that it does not add the ascii code for the delete key(127) to an array that stores all the key strokes entered so far, i.e. the input buffer.  Instead, when you hit the delete key the cmd window is programmed to remove the last key stroke from the array.  It's as simple as:

```
key_strokes = []

#get key_code

if key_code == 127:
    key_strokes.pop()
else:
    key_strokes.append(key_code)
```

The problem is that you need to take control of the program that produced the cmd window to change the way it behaves.

The easiest solution is to make your user enter a 'd' for delete--instead of hitting the delete key.

Otherwise, you need to capture the key stroke as the user types it.  The best and most productive way to respond to key strokes(and not wait for the Enter key) is to learn about Tkinter.  You can present your user with a window that you created--what's called a GUI, and you can program it to do whatever you want when the user hits the delete key:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

def get_key(event):
    print "You pressed", repr(event.char)
entry.bind("<Key>", get_key)

root.mainloop()
```

Another way to do something similar is to use the curses module, which is a colossal waste of time.  The time you spend sorting out curses would be better spent learning Tkinter.

Now, what's going on in your code here:

```
list(k for k in config_dict.keys() if k not in ["mac", "base_url", "command_name"]):
```

Why are you creating a generator and then immediately throwing it away after you extract a list from the generator?  What's the matter with eliminating the generator step:

```
[
    k for k in config_dict.keys() 
    if k not in ["mac", "base_url", "command_name"]
]
```

And it would be even more efficient if you used a set for the "nots" instead of a list.  Having to search through the whole list is not as efficient as one dictionary lookup:

```
[
    k for k in config_dict.keys() 
    if k not in set(["mac", "base_url", "command_name"])
]
```